# Как изменить переменную в другом скрипте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, dict

У меня есть файл main.py и файл blacklist.py. В main.py я объявляю переменную NEW_BLACKLIST (словарь) мне нужно изменить переменную BLACKLIST (словарь) в blacklist.py на данные словаря NEW_BLACKLIST. Как это сделать?

я пытался сделать следующим образом:

```
import blacklist
blacklist.BLACKLIST = NEW_BLACKLIST
```

Но это не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, очень буду благодарен

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71331496/object-assign-equivalent-in-python

Comment: 1. Ваш код у меня отлично работает, значение переменной `blacklist.BLACKLIST` меняется. 2. "Но это не работает." - а как оно должно, на ваш взгляд, работать? Можно привести пример?

Comment: Если Вы обращаетесь к переменной `blacklist.BLACKLIST` в той-же сессии, где меняете ее, то должно работать, если нет, то работать не должно. Опишите более подробно свои действия или представьте более полный код, запустив который, можно воспроизвести описываемую Вами ситуацию